# BuildUrlFromExpression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently looking at this:

[Radchart in ASP.NET MVC](http://andreas-aspace.blogspot.com/2008/07/radchart-in-aspnet-mv.html)

but don't know how to deal with this bit of code:

```
string url = helper.BuildUrlFromExpression<T>(action);
```

Is this a MVC helper method I can just use? Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an extension like this:

```
    public static string Image<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Action<T>> action, int width, int height, string alt)
            where T : Controller
    {
        var expression = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        string actionMethodName = string.Empty;
        if (expression != null)
        {
            actionMethodName = expression.Method.Name;
        }
        string url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection).Action(actionMethodName, typeof(T).Name.Remove(typeof(T).Name.IndexOf("Controller"))).ToString();         
        //string url = LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression<T>(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection, action);
        return string.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" width=\"{1}\" height=\"{2}\" alt=\"{3}\" />", url, width, height, alt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This did the job:

```
string url = Microsoft.Web.Mvc.LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression<T>(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection, action);
```